# Azure Push notification with ionic app

Tags: ionic3

I'm building an ionic3 application and I want to build a push notification , I found more services of notifications like "Azure Hub , Fire base" .
Now what is the best track between those two services ?
What are the advantages of Azure (It's already use FCM) why should I use it as well as using FCM directly ?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?